# 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I keep getting the error: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

I'm unsure where to start as it was working before, but when I went to run my code, I keep getting the float error. The code worked before I changed the initial time to 1 and then back to 0 to play around with it.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# define da/dt = (u-a)/(tau(a,u))

t0 = 0 #inital time in microseconds
a0 = 0.0 # excitation in volts 
tf = 10 # final time in microseconds
dt = 0.1 # time step size
t_act = 0.75 
t_deact = 0.25

#u = 1.0 # inital excitation value in volts - fix excitation

n = int((tf-t0)/dt+1) #number of samples

# defining t values

t = np.linspace(t0,tf,num=n)

# initalizing array for a and u values

a = np.zeros([n])


#excitation signal allocation


for i in range(1,10):

    u.append(1)

for i in range(11,3000):

    u.append(0)


# loop for euler's method

a[1] = a0


for i in range(1,n):

        a[i] = a[i-1] + dt * (((u[i])/t_act) + ((1 - u[i])/t_deact) * (u[i] - a[i-3]))


# plot solution


plt.plot(t,a, 'o')
plt.xlabel("Value of t in ms")
plt.ylabel("Value of excitation in ")
plt.title("Activation Dynamics")
plt.show()
```

I expect to plot t & a, but I'm unsure what to do now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Include the *entire* error message (including trace-back) and delete the superfluous code.

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting `u` to be a list, or an array, or a dataframe, or something similar.  But it isn't; it's a single floating-point number, and you can't `append()` to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set `u` as a float, then try to append, something you cannot do to a 'number', but instead used most often for lists, what are your intentions?

```
u = 1.0

for i in range(1,10):

    u.append(1)

for i in range(11,3000):

    u.append(0)
```

Comment: I want to allocate u as a list from 0 to 3000

Comment: so do you want its contents to be [0, 1, 2, 3 ...3000] or 1's for the first 10, then 0 for the rest up to 3000 items (what I got from the code)?

Comment: 1's for the first 10, and then 0 for the rest up to 3000 items

Comment: Okay, just simply change `u = 1.0` to `u = []`, although I will warn you, the first loop only goes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 it doesn't hit 10. And the second doesnt hit 3000, ends at 2999. How range() works, first number is included, second isnt,